# Problem with adding a point-feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features

Problem: when I add a point-feature to a vector layer it doesn't appear where it is supposed to.

Here's what the process looks like:

1. I create a vector Shapefile with *point* as a geometry type and add two fields (one for North coordinate and one for East coordinate). Field type: Whole number. I apply the same CRS (SWEREF99 TM) as the project has.
2. I turn on toggling for the layer and click on "Add point feature".
3. I click on a random spot on the map and enter the coordinates which I have gathered from a website. The website is a local (Swedish) equivalent of Google Maps. I use it because It provides coordinates for SWEREF99 TM CRS.
4. I insert the coordinates and the point does not land on the spot where it should, rather in the vicinity of it. I even downloaded a georeferenced (SWEREF99 TM) satellite photo of the area and hovered over the spot where the point should be and noted the coordinates. Then I inserted those coordinates into this vector layer and still the point ends up in the wrong place. No matter which way I do it, it always appears in the wrong place, we are talking ca 2 to 10 cm off every time. I even tried inserting North coordinates into East coordinate field and vice versa but nothing works.

Comment: 1: You create a "vector Shapefile with point as a geometry type", but then you "click on `Add line feature`": that cannot work. On a point layer, you have only points, on a line layer only lines. 2: you enter values for coordinates **wehre**: in the attribute table? That's not how creating geometries work - have a look at this tutorial for the basics: https://youtu.be/kCnNWyl9qSE 3: 2 to 10 cm accuracy looks quite good in my opinion - it always depends how much digits you use. So please add more information about what you do and best also add a screenshot. Your problem is not clear to me.

Comment: 1. Oh, my bad. I meant to type "Add point feature". 2. After you click on the "Add point feature" and then click on a random spot on the map then a dialogue window pops up where you enter the coordinates. I do not enter the coordinates in the attribute table. I know that's not how it works. 3. I enter all of the digits. Screenshots of what is it that you would like to see?

Comment: You create two fields and then enter the coordinates when you click on the map: that's exactly adding your coordinate values as attributes. That's not how it works: the geometry will be placed where you click on the map, not where you enter your data. You could however create geometries (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) using `make_point (x,y)`. But much better: prepare a csv table with your data and load that to QGIS. There are a lot of explanations online for that, the first I found is this: https://www.hatarilabs.com/ih-en/how-to-import-spreadsheet-data-into-qgis

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thanks so much for bringing some clarity. Have a good day/night!

Answer (score 2):

If you've already entered a load of points into a layer with the wanted coordinates in the attribute table, you can use the "Create points layer from table" tool to take those coordinates and make a new layer with points at those coordinates. All you do is tell it which layer, which column is the lat and long, and what coordinate system the coordinates are in:

[image]

You'll get a new layer at the exact entered coordinate points.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Much appreciated!

Comment: @ViktorSulakvelidze-Skantz, please keep in mind [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).